# Cannot pass variable of type conforming to generic constraint

Tags: c#, generics, interface, generic-constraints

```
public interface ILovable<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    T Care(T t);
}

public class Me : ILovable<int>
{
    public int Care(int i)
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Say I have the above. Now below function fails:

```
private static void Colour<T>(ILovable<T> me) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    var z = me.Care(1); //cannot convert from 'int' to 'T'
}
```

What's failing the above piece of code? `ILovable<T>` has a `Care` function which intakes a `T` which is `IEquatable<T>`. In the above function I'm calling the same `Care` function and passing `T` which is `int` type. `int` is after all `IEquatable<int>`.

*What am I doing wrong? Is there any work around to get it fixed?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is overriding variable of type `T` inside a generic method (or class) with a more derived type is not possible since compiler doesn't explicitly know `T` is that more derived type (in our case `T` is `int`), because `T` can be any other more derived type at run time.

Long answer: `me` variable is of type `ILovable<T>`. Now `me.Care` function is expecting parameter of type that is specified on `ILovable<T>` which is `T`. Outside the `Care` function `T` can be anything that is `IEquatable<T>`, so `int` is ok. But inside the function, `T` has to be just `T` and not another derived type of `IEquatable<T>`. Otherwise there will be runtime error for scenarios like this:

```
private static void Colour<T>(ILovable<T> me) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    var z = me.Care(1); 
}

...

Colour("");
```

Right now, `T` is string when calling `Colour("")`. So `me` is `ILovable<string>`. So `me.Care` function expects a `string` as parameter but provided is an `int` and that is disaster.

Answer (score 3):

Your method signature does not specify a `ILovable<int>`, it specifies an `ILovable<T>`.  This, for example, would work:

```
private static void Colour(ILovable<int> me)
{
    var z = me.Care(1); //cannot convert from 'int' to 'T'
}
```

The problem is the compiler doesn't know that `T` is an 'int' in your example; it could be any type that meets the constraint.  Here is another way that would work:

```
private static void Colour<T>(ILovable<T> me, T valueToCareAbout) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    var z = me.Care(valueToCareAbout);
}
//use like this
Colour(me, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error I get is:

```
Argument type 'int' is not assignable to parameter type 'T'
```

I'm pretty sure this is because you are defining `me` as an `ILovable<T>`.  Therefore, it doesn't automatically resolve to the `Me` type where int is defined as `T`.

This will fix the error because `Me` defines `T` as an `int`:

```
private static void Colour<T>(Me me) where T : IEquatable<T>
        {
            var z = me.Care(1); 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that's because method Colour says that there will be parameter of type ILovable< T >  whereas T would be resolved later, so at compile time either I tell method that T is int type.

So either you pass ILovable as parameter and grantee that T is int

```
void Colour<T>(ILovable<int> me)
```

or pass type Me directly

```
void Colour<T>(Me me)
```

Because otherwise me.Care is expecting type T not int as specific

Answer (score 1):

Change following

```
private static void Colour<T>(ILovable<T> me) where T : IEquatable<T>
```

To

```
private static void Colour<Int32>(ILovable<int> me)
```

and above will work.

---

Now the mystry portion

You are getting error in following

```
private static void Colour<T>(ILovable<T> me) where T : IEquatable<T>
```

because `Care` is expecting `T`, and you are providing `int`.
It is same as

`Care((T)1)`.

or

```
 T t = (T)1; //This is the cause of error as int cannot be changed to T. Remember Int32 is sealed so T cannot derive from int

 Care(t); // This is fine
```

To make above work, `T` has to `int`. To make it so, Colur method syntax should be like

```
   private static void Colour<Int32>(ILovable<int> me)
```

If you want to pass string to `Care`, `T` should be `string`.

```
  private static void Colour<string>(ILovable<string> me) 
  {
     me.Care("Hello");
  }
```

Now if we have to fix T then question arises why T is required at all in `Colour` definition.

Answer -> For non taking care of inheritance type in non sealed class.